# Correspondence principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is there a precise mathematical derivation for the correspondence principle for which I can replace $E \rightarrow i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $p \rightarrow -i \hbar \nabla$?

Comment: Assumption that in quantum mechanics particles are waves $\exp(-i E t / \hbar + i \vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}/\hbar  )$.

Comment: $(E,\mathbf p) \mapsto i\hbar(\partial_t, -\nabla)$ is *not* the commonly known [correspondence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Derivation

Comment: for example, when we get the Dirac equation from the equation of relativistic dispersion. For the Yukawa potential for the meson is made a similar transition. I wonder if it is always possible.

Comment: The basic way to convert between classical and quantum mechanics is to replace a Poisson bracket (in Hamiltonian mechanics) by $i\hbar$ times the commutator.

Comment: As far as I know, they are definitions, so they are not really derived mathematically...

Comment: Usually this is taken as an axiom. However you may ask if there is an axiomatic framework of quantum mechanics (which doesn't use the correspondence principle as an axiom), where the correspondence principle is a theorem (i.e. implied by the other postulates) and not an axiom.

Comment: @Noldorin I think you mean $-\frac{i}{\hbar}$ times the commutator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different ways to establish this correspondence, eg, using Lie groups or Fourier Transform. But, in the end of the day, the notion that this takes one from Classical to Quantum Mechanics is nothing but an 'axiom'. So, in this sense, it's a bit weird to use the word "derive" the principle: this 'principle' is used as one of the *axioms* that *defines* Quantum Mechanics.

In any case, von Neumann was probably the one to first formalize this construction in terms of what he called "Transformation Theory", which is the theory of [Fourier Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships) for distributions (generalized functions).